# Deciding user class place in the application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, domain-driven-design, application-design

I quite not sure about how it all should work. So I have an aggregate in my domain model (`Post`->`Feedbacks`;`Post`->`Category`). And I've been thinking about place of `User` class. My first thought was to implement `User` class using *state pattern*:

```
interface IUserRole
{
    // for example we got something like this:
    Boolean CanPost { get; }
    Boolean CanEdit { get; }
    Boolean CanFlag { get; }

    void AssignRole(IUserRole role, User user);
}

public sealed class AdministratorRole : IUserRole
{
    public Boolean CanPost { get { return true; } }
    public Boolean CanEdit { get { return true; } }
    public Boolean CanFlag { get { return true; } }

    public void AssignRole(IUserRole role, User user)
    {
        user.Role = role;
    }
}
public sealed class NewMemberRole : IUserRole
{
    public Boolean CanPost { get { return true; } }
    public Boolean CanEdit { get { return false; } }
    public Boolean CanFlag { get { return false; } }

    public void AssignRole(IUserRole role, User user)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("text");
    }

}

public class User // : Entity<User>
{
    private IUserRole role;
    public class User(String name, String pwd, IUserRole role)
    {
        // ...
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Boolean CanPost { get { return this.role.CanPost; } }
    public Boolean CanEdit { get { return this.role.CanEdit; } }
    public Boolean CanFlag { get { return this.role.CanFlag; } }

    public void AssignRole(IUserRole role, User)
    {
        this.role.AssignRole(role, user);
    }

    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

On that step I've been considering to include `User` into domain model then to use it thru NHibernate DAL/DAO.

I've read about `MembershipUser` and `MembershipProvider`. And all authentification stuff is implemented in standard `ASP.NET MVC` template.

So if I use standard *membership/membership-user* where will the domain logic go? Should I then restrict operation over `Post` entity thru setting `Authorize` attribute on actions .. so they will work as permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in ASP.NET MVC applications, you have the ability to *authorize/deny* some *users/roles* on actions.
It works with the membership provider defined in the project.

.NET is shipped by default with 2 membership providers: one for sqlserver, with some scripts to run, and another one based on ActiveDirectory membership.

You can also make your own `Membership` and `Role` providers. This way you'll have the membership provider customized for your domain objects/behavior.